# Installing a remote Tomcat server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to deploy and debug a local web application using a remote instance of Eclipse. I went through the normal "Create a server" wizard and specified my hostname as show below:

[image: Define a New Server]

However, the next step requires I specify a local tomcat directory. How can I specify a remote location instead?

[image]

Comment: You can't. Install and configure on the remote machine. Edit: You might, if you can tolerate installation on NFS shares. But that is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Interesting though, I could use Samba :) Why do you think that's not a good idea?

Comment: Hmm, that could work. I didn't know you wanted to install on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have started tomcat process with the [appropriate debug options](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation), the way to remote debug (webapp or standalone app) is to setup a "Remote Java Application" debug configuration for your webapp project in eclipse.

(Available via Run->Debug Configurations->Remote Java application)

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is currently the only option.

Answer (score 2):

For deploying the local application to a remote Tomcat, you can also use the [Tomcat Ant deploy tasks and manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant) and use the debug technique described by @amol.