# is it possible to use eclipse on windows but connected to tomcat7 on linux?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

i have eclipse on my windows 7 but I want to connected to the tomcat7 on my ubuntu server so it updates directly without having to keep moving the .war file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing a remote Tomcat server in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946390/installing-a-remote-tomcat-server-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is use Continuous integration tools such CruiseControl to do it
http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/