# Adding Tomcat server remotely to Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, servlets

Normally in Eclipse we run, Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

Can we add a tomcat which is located remotely on another IP address?

Currently, I'm running programs in Windows. I need it to be run with tomcat server which is located on another IP address on Linux.

Comment: Refer This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946390/installing-a-remote-tomcat-server-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Convert your web project to Maven Project and copy and paste the below code to your pom file.

```
<project ...>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://yourhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hey whats the use of maven. I didn't get you @Navneet  :-( could u plz tell me?

Comment: k will try (y) to do

Answer (score 0):

Convert your web project to Maven Project and copy and paste the below code to your pom file.

org.apache.tomcat.maventomcat7-maven-plugin2.1http://yourhost:8080/manager/text

Yes the above code is working you need to configure remote ip to url section.